# Can a Casted Weapon be cast again?

Tags: the-secret-world

In The Secret World, there are Casting Toolkits which allow you to destroy a weapon and then allow you to apply its visual look to another weapon of that type. I got a Tyrfing from Polaris which I love the look of Very Much, and would like to apply it to the Blade that I'm questing with now, but I'd **also** like to take that blade that I cast Tyrfing onto and "recover" Tyrfing's look from it and apply it to something else in the future (say, something from Nightmares or what have you). If I cast Tyrfing's look onto what I'm wielding now, can I later use a Casting Toolkit on the blade I'm using and apply it to something else? If I can, will that use the normal look of my blade, or will it use Tyrfing's look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes You can.  Using a casting kit on any weapon transfers the current look of that weapon and not the original, so you can continue to have your favorite weapon style as you upgrade your weapons throughout your secret world career